# Numpy dot operation finished quickly but continuously occupies high CPU time

Tags: python, numpy

Here is a simple code that calculate the dot product of a vector and a matrix.

```
import numpy as np
import time

a = np.arange(2048)
b = np.random.random((2048, 24))
while True:
    starttime = time.time()
    c = a.dot(b)
    print(f'Calculated in {time.time() - starttime:.2f} seconds.')
    time.sleep(1)
```

The speed of the above operation is fast as expected. The code constantly output:

```
Calculated in 0.00 seconds.
Calculated in 0.00 seconds.
Calculated in 0.00 seconds.
...
```

However, when I look at the task manager, I see the process constantly occupies a whole CPU core or thread: 
~12% in a 6 core 12 threads CPU. 
It seems that the instruction `time.sleep(1)` was not working at all.

This problem has been reproduced many times in X86-X64 platform with Ubuntu 1804 and Windows 10, and also ARM platform with Ubuntu1804. If I do NOT use `numpy.dot`, everything is OK. The CPU usage is below 1%. But, when a `numpy.dot` operation was inserted, the CPU usage jumped up to 12%. Does anybody have similar experiences? It is really hard to understand it.

Follow @AMC's suggestion, I have tried different sleep time.

```
time.sleep(1): 12%, 
time.sleep(2): 4%-7%, 
time.sleep(3): ~3.8%, 
time.sleep(4): 0%-4%
```

In all cases, the `time.time()-starttime` is constantly 0.00 seconds. It seems `numpy.dot` finished calculations quickly but still occupied CPU for a while.

Thanks a lot for reading.

Comment: is the question about numpy or about sleep? can your reproduce this with anything else?

Comment: I don't think there is enough information here to find a solid answer. There are so many possible causes.

Comment: @ Paul H, thanks. I think this question is about the behavior of numpy.dot during sleep. I have reproduced this problem many times in X86-X64 platform with Ubuntu 1804 and Windows 10, and also ARM platform with Ubuntu1804. If I do NOT use numpy.dot, everything is OK. The CPU usage is below 1%. But, when a numpy.dot operation was inserted, the CPU usage jumped up to 12%.

Comment: @AMC, thanks. The numpy.dot operation is the exact cause of high CPU usage. Initially, I wrote a function that has many operations and found high CPU usage. I delete instructions one by one to see which one was responsible. Finally, I found numpy.dot is the exact cause of high CPU usage even if there is a time.sleep followed.

Comment: @TanYi What happens when you sleep longer than a few seconds?

Comment: @AMC good suggestion. time.sleep(1): 12%, time.sleep(2): 4%-7%, time.sleep(3): ~3.8%, time.sleep(4): 0%-4%

Comment: But in all cases, the time.time()-starttime is constantly 0.00 seconds. It seems numpy.dot finished calculations quickly but still occupied CPU for a while.

Comment: What is the temporal resolution of your cpu usage measurement? If the calculation takes eg. 0.5s with full cpu-load and 0.5s sleep, you will see 50% averaged CPU load with 1s temporal resolution.

Comment: @max9111, you are right. The temporal resolution of CPU usage is about 1 second. But it doesn't affect the problem. The strange point is that numpy.dot finished all calculation but still occupied CPU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def dot(a,b):
    length = b.shape[1]
    c = np.zeros(length)
    for i in np.arange(length):
        c[i] = np.inner(a,b[:,i])
    return c
```

The reason why `np.dot` consumes so much CPU time is still unknown. However, by replacing the `np.dot` by the function above, it seems fixed. Now the same operation costs only 0.1% CPU usage.